# Синонимы: гсч, random, math.random(?)

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, замена-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки [гсч](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%81%d1%87) (7), [random](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random) (43). Еще есть одинокий [math.random](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math.random) с одним вопросом, может быть и его стоит в кучу.

Update: [теория-вероятностей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9), [rand](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rand) тоже в этом списке.

Текущее состояние дел:

Следующие теги вычищены из постов и синонимизированы к [случайные-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0):

- `гсч`
- `random`
- `math.random`
- `rand`

`теория-вероятностей` пока решено оставить.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Главной меткой должны стать [случайные-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0). Как общий случай, касающийся не только генераторов.

Comment: А как еще в программировании появляются (псевдо)случайные числа, кроме как из генератора?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вопрос может затрагивать, например, теорвер, распределение случайных величин или что-то подобное (в контексте программирования, конечно). Ну и, на мой взгляд, *генератор-случайных-чисел* длинновато, а *гсч* коротковато. Но меня в конечном счете любой вариант устроит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как откуда? Из [головы](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @Nofate что с синонимизацией? Вроде бы есть очевидный лидер, предлагаю уже реализовать.

Answer (score -1):

Главной меткой должна стать [генератор-случайных-чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb). Как раз максимальные 25 символов и для поиска оптимально.

Comment: Слишком длинно и сужает суть вопросов. Я за [tag:случайные-числа].